# Windows 10 extend display both sides

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, external-display, extended-desktop

I have one monitor connected to my laptop. I sometimes put my laptop one the left side and sometimes on the right.
I think on Windows you can only have extended monitor on one side.
But why can't the displays be placed like on a cylinder so that when I move the cursor to the **right** corner of my laptop it will appear on the **left** corner on the monitor and when I move the cursor to the **left** corner of my laptop it will appear on the **right** cornet of the external display.

Is there some software that does it? I can't even formulate correct google search.